# UWP Run Query as typeing - MVVM

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, uwp, event-handling

I am creating a UWP app for the company I work for and one of the requests is to run a search query as they type. I have successfully done it but I broke the MVVM model to do it. Here is my current code and if there is a way to make it more MVVM friendly and give others an example to work with would be great.

VIEW:

```
<TextBox x:Name="SearchTxtBx" PlaceholderText="Search..." Visibility="Collapsed" Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.SearchValue, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Row="6" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" KeyUp="SearchTxtBx_KeyUp" />
```

CODE BEHIND:

```
 private void SearchTxtBx_KeyUp(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((bool)FNSearchOpt.IsChecked || (bool)LNSearchOpt.IsChecked)
        {
            var testText = SearchTxtBx.Text;

            ViewModel.GetSearchResults(testText);
        }

    }
```

VIEWMODEL:

```
 public void GetSearchResults(string typedText = "")
    {
        string queryString = "";

        if((FNSearchCheck || LNSearchCheck) && !typedText.isNullOrWhiteSpace())
        {
            SearchValue = typedText;
        }
```

The problem I run into when going straight to the method in the Viewmodel is that it will not update the property until it loses focus so the search value is null unless I use the code behind to set it.

Again any help making this more MVVM friendly would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the `UpdateSourceTrigger` property to `PropertyChanged`:

```
<TextBox ... Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.SearchValue, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ... />
```

Then the source property (`ViewModel.SearchValue`) should be updated whenever the binding target value changes, i.e. on each key stroke.

Comment: Thank you that is exactly what I was looking for!